# Simplify set expression using property law

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Simplify the following set expression Ā ⋃ (U ⋂ (B⋃A)) by applying set theory law

Step 1 apply distributive law, Ā ⋃ ((U ⋂ B) ⋃ (U ⋂ A))

Step 2 apply identify laws, Ā ⋃ (B ⋃ A)

Is it still possible to simplify further from step 2?

Comment: You don't even need distributivity. On the premise $U$ is a universal set, it immediately folllows $U \cap X = X$ for all sets $X$, including $X = B \cup A$ (though I think you meant $C$ in your statement of the problem, not $A$). That said, the only simplification I can think of is removing the parentheses since $\cup$ is associative on sets.

Comment: Corrected my set expression in the post. Is there some sort of a law for universal set for U∩X=X? The question actually didn't mention about universal set, I suppose I will just assume U is universal?

Comment: For associative law, is it possible for the expression to be rearrange to (Ā ⋃ A) ⋃ B from Ā ⋃ (B ⋃ A)? I believe the law state that it will not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if by $\bar{A}$ you mean $U \setminus A$ and if also $A, B \subseteq U$, then the last expression becomes $U$.

$\bar{A} \cup (B \cup A) = \bar{A} \cup ( A \cup B) = (\bar{A} \cup A) \cup B = U \cup B = U.$

Comment: Thank you, I have derive the same solution as you using the laws. Going to mark this as the answer.

Comment: You're welcome and good job solving it yourself. To answer the questions you asked in your comments. By universal set $U$ is meant a set which contains the other sets so in this case it just means $A, B \subseteq U$. And then you can prove the following that for any $A \subseteq U$ implies $A \cap U = A$. And similarly, for any $A \subseteq U$ it implies $A \cup U = U$.